# error undefined for defined constructor

Tags: java, user-interface, compiler-errors, system-calls

I'm getting an error that i have been working on, on the side for some time the error is "The constructor HangmanPanel() is undefined" but i defined this in Hangman().., I think it may want me to use parameters but I'm not sure which ones....

Hangman.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Hangman extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6224212014648478637L;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Hangman();

    }

    public Hangman() {
        this.setSize(800, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Hangman Web App");

        HangmanPanel panel = new HangmanPanel();
        this.add(panel);

        this.setVisible(true);
        }

}
```

HangmanPanel.java

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class HangmanPanel extends JPanel {
    static Boolean FOUND;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5793357804828609325L;

    public static String answerKey() {
        //get random array element
        String array[] = new String[10];
        array[0] = "hamlet";
        array[1] = "mysts of avalon";
        array[2] = "the iliad";
        array[3] = "tales from edger allan poe";
        array[4] = "the children of hurin";
        array[5] = "the red b" +
                "+adge of courage";
        array[6] = "of mice and men";
        array[7] =  "utopia"; 
        array[8] =  "chariots of the gods";
        array[9] =  "a brief history of time";

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String s = list.get(0);
        return s;
    }

    public StringBuilder dashReplace(String s) {
        //replace non-white space char with dashes and creates StringBuilder Object
        String tW = s.replaceAll("\\S", "-"); 
        System.out.print(tW + "\n");  
        StringBuilder AnswerKey = new StringBuilder(tW);
        return AnswerKey;
    }
    public static int findAndReplace(String s, JLabel answerKey, String sc,
            char ch) {
        //find position of user input and replace
        int pos = -1;
        FOUND = false;
        while(true){
        pos = s.indexOf(sc, pos+1);
        if(pos < 0){

            break;
        }else{
            FOUND = true;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(answerKey.getText());
            builder.setCharAt(pos, ch);
            answerKey.setText(builder.toString());
        }

        }
        JLabel AnswerKey2 = new JLabel(answerKey.toString());
        return pos;
    }




    public HangmanPanel(final String s){
        this.setLayout(null);

        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Welcome to the Hangman App");
        JButton Button = new JButton("Ok");
        //get input

        JLabel tfLable = new JLabel("Please Enter a Letter:");


        final JLabel AnswerKey = new JLabel(dashReplace(answerKey()).toString());

        final JTextField text = new JTextField(10);


        heading.setSize(200, 50);
        tfLable.setSize(150, 50);
        text.setSize(50, 30);
        Button.setSize(60, 20);
        AnswerKey.setSize(200, 100);

        heading.setLocation(300, 10);
        tfLable.setLocation(50, 40);
        text.setLocation(50, 80);
        Button.setLocation(100, 85);
        AnswerKey.setLocation(100,85);

        this.add(heading);
        this.add(tfLable);
        this.add(text);
        this.add(Button);
        this.add(AnswerKey);


        Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // can't access text
                String sc = text.getText();
                char ch = sc.charAt(0);
                findAndReplace(s, AnswerKey, sc, ch);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to pass `String` parameter to HangmanPanel constructor like this: `new HangmanPanel("some-string")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message refers to the class HangManPanel not having a constructor HangManPanel(). Question for you: given this understanding of the error message, can you look at your code and see why the compiler might be telling you this?

Comment: There are many things i don't yet understand I'm new to programing, newer to java, and have only been working with gui's since yesterday... this error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor HangmanPanel() is undefined

 at Hangman.<init>(Hangman.java:19)
 at Hangman.main(Hangman.java:10)

Comment: your saying i can put a method called HangManPanel() as the constructor? what dose the constructor do? how would i be used an for what?

Comment: For more background, when you call "new" it calls the constructor for whatever class you are calling new on.  So, for example, in this line:

    HangmanPanel panel = new HangmanPanel();

The part "new HangmanPanel()" tells your code to run the "constructor" in HangmanPanel with no parameters (because the () is empty).

The constructor is the method with the same name as the class.
In the HangmanPanel class above there is only one constructor, and it is a constructor that requires a string. Instead it accepts a string. You can either add a parameterless constructor or call the one with string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a parameterless constructor in `HangmanPanel`

if you change it to

```
    HangmanPanel panel = new HangmanPanel("some appropriate string");
```

it should compile

Comment: this is what i thought was wrong but wouldn't putting some string in there break my code? how would this String interact with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You only have a constructor defined in HangManPanel which accepts a string, there is no other constructor.

add `public HangmanPanel()` to your class HangmanPanet

Comment: Darn you let the cat out of the bag. :-) I was going to have Sage1216 think about this one . . .